# Native base Latest Version not work in EXPO snack

Tags: react-native, expo, font-awesome-5

I have just created a new snack and add native base library with the instructions provided by Native base documentation for expo:

Here is the instructions i have followed:

```
// At the top of your file
import { Font } from 'expo';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

// Later on in your component
async componentDidMount() {
  await Font.loadAsync({
    'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
    'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
    ...Ionicons.font,
  });
}
```

But It shows Error As Unable to resolve module FontAwesome5.js 
[image]

Please Suggest me some solution for the same

Here is my Snack Link for the same.

https://snack.expo.io/@simransingh/native-base

Thanks.

Comment: I've noticed that too. The only workaround that I found was to work locally. It appears to be an issue with `snack`. You could always open an issue with [Expo](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues) or with [Native Base](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I just found the solution for the same ,

It's because of FontAwesome5 not loaded properly ,

You can import it from @expo/vector-icons

Here is the working snack:

https://snack.expo.io/@simransingh/native-base

Answer (score 0):

yep this problem happend to me in snack i just solved it by changing the version of nativebase from latest to previous version

{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "2.2.8",
    "native-base": "latest"
  }
}

change to

{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-paper": "2.2.8",
    "native-base": "2.12.1"
  }
}